# How do I parse nested JSON-objects in SQL?

Tags: sql, arrays, json, object, ssms

I have a string of JSON, returned by an API, that looks something like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "transactions": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "text": "debet",
            "invoiceAmount": "1.0000"
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "text": "kredit",
            "invoiceAmount": "-1.0000"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

It is valid JSON, however the only way that I am able to parse in sql is by manipulating the string first. Like this:

```
[
  {
    "node": {
      "text": "debet",
      "invoiceAmount": "1.0000"
    }
  },
  {
    "node": {
      "text": "kredit",
      "invoiceAmount": "-1.0000"
    }
  }
]
```

E.g. below. How do I achieve this without manipulating the string?

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @json = N'[{"node":{"text":"debet","invoiceAmount":"1.0000"}},{"node":{"text":"kredit","invoiceAmount":"-1.0000"}}]';

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json)  
  WITH (
    text NVARCHAR(50) '$.node.text',
    invoiceAmount MONEY '$.node.surname'
  )
```

I tried $.data.transactions.edges.node.text. SQL returns NULL

Comment: Hi - please tag your question with the DBMS you are using and also update your question with some sample output that you want to achieve based on the JSON you’ve given

Comment: I use SSMS. Output should be a table of the two fields, text and invoice amount, and the two rows  (array).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY(@json, '$.data.transactions.edges'))  
  WITH (
    text VARCHAR(100) '$.node.text',    
    invoiceAmount DECIMAL(10,4) '$.node.invoiceAmount'
  )
```

to get the desired values out of your original string.

([DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1_eKedlT))

The [`JSON_QUERY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) first extracts the array and then that is expanded out with [`OPENJSON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).